# .net core - How to properly kill started process?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a dotnet core 2.0 console app that starts up another dotnet core WebAPI.
The problem is, how do I cleanly kill the WebAPI process when the console app is closed? Because as of now, I can't start the process twice since it gives an error the address is in use, and I can still see the process in the task manager.

Here is how I tried to do that but seems like it's missing something to completely kill all the processes:

```
class Program
{
    static Process cmd;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        };

        cmd = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };

        cmd.Start();

        using (cmd)
        {
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine($"cd C:/Project/publish");
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine($"dotnet WebAPI.dll");
            cmd.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.GetProcessById(cmd.Id).Kill();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails to kill all processes"? Does your services spawn other processes again? Then this won't help, because kill is not recursive. I suggest you think about a solution for terminating all processes nicely. Killing should always be the last option, as it may lead to data loss.

Comment: @mjwills, You said: "It seems odd to launch cmd.exe to run dotnet. You should just launch dotnet directly." So, what do you mean by running `dotnet` directly?

Comment: @mjwills - Works great! Don't know why I didn't think of that before :-) I think it would be best to post a code sample with a full solution. Would you like me to post it or will you?

Comment: @mjwills, Posted with credits to you. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @mjwills I've updated the process as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static Process webAPI;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;

        webAPI = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet")
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                WorkingDirectory = "C:/Project/publish",
                Arguments = "WebAPI.dll",
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        using (webAPI)
        {
            webAPI.Start();
            webAPI.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webAPI.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: if I am not wrong webAPI.Close(); only frees all the resources that are associated with this process. Then how you killed the child process.

Comment: @RPrashant, I'm not sure I understand your question. `webAPI.Close()` means that when the (parent) console app that started the `webAPI` process exits, the (childe) `webAPI` process will also be closed.

Comment: but in my case it is not closing the child process.
I can still see the process in the task manager.

Comment: @RPrashant, You can use a second approach for doing it by monitoring the parent process from the child process like this: `Process process = Process.GetProcessById(PARENT_PROCESS_ID);
Task.Run(() => process.WaitForExit()).ContinueWith(t => Environment.Exit(-1));` For this to work you'll need to pass the parent's process id to the child process.

Comment: I have asked my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127334/net-core-console-app-as-windows-service-is-it-possible-to-safely-kill-executio).
Could you please check this

Comment: @RPrashant, I've posted an answer for you there.

Answer (score 0):

You can terminate the application with the `Kill()` method of the current process.

**Startup.cs**

```
        public void Configure(IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
        {
            //...

            appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to shut down.");
            });

            appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shutting down...");
                System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            });
        }
```

---

**Program.cs**

Don't forget to use `UseConsoleLifetime()` while building the host.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseConsoleLifetime(opts => opts.SuppressStatusMessages = true);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 class first_class{

static Process[] cmd=new Process[size];
      int main(){
           cmd[0] = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };

           cmd[0].Start();
      }
};
```

===============================================

```
ref class otherClass{

first_class::cmd[0].Kill();

};
```