# .net core console app as windows service- Is it possible to safely kill execution of started process without using Kill() method?

Tags: c#, process, windows-services, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a dotnet core 2.2 console app.
I hosted it as windows service.(Service name: "MyService1")
"MyService1" starts up another dotnet core WebAPI.
The problem is, how do I safely kill the WebAPI process when the "MyService1" is stopped?

Here is how I tried to do that but  I can still see the process in the task manager.

```
public class MyService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer;
    static Process webAPI;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(
            (e) => StartChildProcess(),
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void StartChildProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            webAPI = new Process();
            webAPI.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            webAPI.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Project\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\publish\WebAPI.exe";
            webAPI.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // TODO: Add code to stop child process safely
        webAPI.Close();  

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do that without using Kill() method?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're starting your other WebAPI process from, nut you have 2 options:

1. Register to the `ProcessExit` event from your `Program.cs` file and close the WebAPI 
   process there, like this:

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static Process webAPI;

       static async Task Main(string[] args)
       {
           AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;

           webAPI = new Process
           {
               StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet")
               {
                   UseShellExecute = false,
                   CreateNoWindow = true,

                   //If you want to run as .exe
                   FileName = @"C:\Project\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\publish\WebAPI.exe",

                   //If you want to run the .dll
                   WorkingDirectory = "C:/Project/publish",
                   Arguments = "WebAPI.dll"
               }
           };
           using (webAPI)
           {
               webAPI.Start();
               webAPI.WaitForExit();
           }
       }

       static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           webAPI.Close();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Pass the service process id to the WebAPI process and monitor it from there, like this:

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static async Task Main(string[] args)
       {
           try { }
           catch { }
           // Make sure you use a finally block.
           // If for any reason your code crashes you'd still want this part to run.
           finally
           {
               if (int.TryPasre(args[X], out parentProcessId))
                   MonitorAgentProcess(parentProcessId);
           }
       }

       static void MonitorAgentProcess(int parentProcessId)
       {
           try
           {
               Process process = Process.GetProcessById(parentProcessId);
               Task.Run(() => process.WaitForExit())
                   .ContinueWith(t => Environment.Exit(-1));
           }
           catch {}
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I am using example given [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/running-net-core-generic-host-applications-as-a-windows-service)

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I used 1st way,  but I can still see the process(WebAPI.exe) in the task manager.
It is not killing the process(WebAPI.exe)

Comment: Try to take the `webApi` process id and kill it using `Process.Kill()`

Comment: Is it possible without using Kill() method? Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you try the second approach?

Comment: Thanks, but 2nd approach is not useful for me. Using first approach is it possible?

Comment: First approach should also work, maybe you have some tasks running and that's keeping the process from being closed. Try to see if killing it works, if so than check your code for running tasks.

Comment: the first approach working only in console application.
But if I hosted it as windows service it is not closing child process.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm actually running this sample as a windows service as well and it works. Try checking your event viewer for any errors.

Comment: There is no error in event viewer.
I will give you brief explanation regarding what steps I am doing.
Step1: Hosted console application as windows service
Step2: Created service using command "sc create service_name binPath="{exe path}
Step3: Started service using command "sc start service_name"
Step4: Stopped service using command "sc stop service_name"

Result: Parent is stopped but I can see child in task manager.

Are you doing the same steps?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have there is that your webAPI task is actually a separate EXE, not integrated into the service. Unless the service has a way of interacting with it and requesting a graceful shut-down then you will have to terminate the EXE process in a manor that is decidedly not clean.

Comment: I am referring the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896621/net-core-how-to-properly-kill-started-process)